# Validate and change different date formats in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, date-format

This is the continues of this problem([Validate and change the date formats in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078678/validate-and-change-the-date-formats-in-pyspark/69078768#69078768))
In the above scenario the solution was perfect but what if I have timestamp date formats and some more different date formats like below.

```
df = sc.parallelize([['12-21-2006'],
                     ['05/30/2007'],
                     ['01-01-1984'],
                     ['22-12-2017'],
                     ['12222019'],
                     ['2020/12/23'],
                     ['2020-12-23'],
                     ['12.11.2020'],
                     ['22/02/2012'],
                     ['2020/12/23 04:50:10'],
                     ['12/23/1996 05:56:20'],
                     ['23/12/2002 10:30:50'],
                     ['24.12.1990'],
                     ['12/03/20']]).toDF(["Date"])

df.show()

+-------------------+
|               Date|
+-------------------+
|         12-21-2006|
|         05/30/2007|
|         01-01-1984|
|         22-12-2017|
|           12222019|
|         2020/12/23|
|         2020-12-23|
|         12.11.2020|
|         22/02/2012|
|2020/12/23 04:50:10|
|12/23/1996 05:56:20|
|23/12/2002 10:30:50|
|         24.12.1990|
|           12/03/20|
+-------------------+
```

When I tried the same way of solving this([Validate and change the date formats in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69078678/validate-and-change-the-date-formats-in-pyspark/69078768#69078768)). There is an error which I am getting. As far as I know the error is due to time stamp formats and the record with similar `MM/dd/yyy, dd/MM/yyyy` are notable to convert into the required format.

```
sdf = df.withColumn("d1", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'yyyy/MM/dd')) \
  .withColumn("d2", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'yyyy-MM-dd')) \
  .withColumn("d3", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'MM/dd/yyyy')) \
  .withColumn("d4", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'MM-dd-yyyy')) \
  .withColumn("d5", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'MMddyyyy')) \
  .withColumn("d6", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'MM.dd.yyyy')) \
  .withColumn("d7", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'dd-MM-yyyy')) \
  .withColumn("d8", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'dd/MM/yy')) \
  .withColumn("d9", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'yyyy/MM/dd HH:MM:SS'))\
  .withColumn("d10", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS'))\
  .withColumn("d11", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS'))\
  .withColumn("d12", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'dd.MM.yyyy')) \
  .withColumn("d13", F.to_date(F.col("Date"),'dd-MM-yy')) \
  .withColumn("result", F.coalesce("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4",'d5','d6','d7','d8','d9','d10','d11','d12','d13')) 
sdf.show()


org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 34.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 34.0 (TID 34, ip-10-191-0-117.eu-west-1.compute.internal, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkUpgradeException: You may get a different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: Fail to parse &#39;01-01-1984&#39; in the new parser. You can set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy to LEGACY to restore the behavior before Spark 3.0, or set to CORRECTED and treat it as an invalid datetime string.
```

Is there any better way of solving this? I just want to know the perfect function library that can convert any kind of date format into a single date format.

Comment: have you tried setting the property `timeParserPolicy` to `LEGACY` - 
`sc.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")`

Comment: @Vaebhav No, Not aware of this. What does it do?

Comment: Search for `timeParser` - https://jaceklaskowski.github.io/mastering-spark-sql-book/configuration-properties/#sparksqllegacycteprecedencepolicy

Comment: Additional link - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html

Comment: Since you are using spark 3.x , for parsing certain date formats thats required in a nutshell